# How do you add items to a ListViewBox with columns?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview

I'm trying to learn how to use the WPF ListViewBoxes in VB.Net.

I can add items to it, as long as there is only one column, by using this:

```
listview.Items.Add(item)
```

However, now that I've added more columns I can't figure out how to add separate items to each column. I've tried using arrays and ListViewItems, but I can't seem to figure it out.
I've read about bindings, but can only seem to find documentation for c#.

This is probably easy and I'm missing something obvious, but how is it done?

Comment: item.Subitem.Add(). Subitem goes to right (column), item goes down (row).

Comment: This is a very good tutorial on WPF. It covers most of the controls. https://wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/introduction/

Comment: @CruleD Using `list1.Items.Add("Test")` then `list1.Items.Item(0).Subitem.Add("test2")` gives the error "Public member 'Subitem' on type 'String' not found."

Comment: @CruleD : OP is using WPF, not WinForms.